# FBSDKContainerViewController my_shouldAutorotate crash after updating to iOS 9.3.4

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, ios9, facebook-ios-sdk

I've updated my iOS to 9.3.4 and I got a crash issue when trying to login with `Facebook SDK`.

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init]; 
[login logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends", @"user_birthday"] fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) { 
    if (error) 
    { 
        NSLog(@"Process error"); 
    } 
    else if (result.isCancelled) 
    { 
        NSLog(@"Cancelled"); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        NSLog(@"Logged in"); [self getFacebookData]; 
    } 
}];
```

> Log : [FBSDKContainerViewController my_shouldAutorotate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13c6e45a0

Comment: Could you share some code? We can't really help you at this point.

Comment: @ Pilatus, ok sure let me share the code with you...

  FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login
     logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends", @"user_birthday"]
     fromViewController:self
     handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
         if (error) {
             NSLog(@"Process error");
         } else if (result.isCancelled) {
             NSLog(@"Cancelled");
         } else {
             NSLog(@"Logged in");
             [self getFacebookData];
         }
     }];

Comment: @Pilatus , I would like to inform you one more thing, I got the same issue when I try to present a view controller like this ....(But it was fine in before OS update)
    ImageViewController *imgViewer = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"imageView"];
    [self presentViewController:imgViewer animated:YES completion:^{
        
    }];